# notification icon gets cropped

Tags: android, notifications

I use notification in my app and I have problem with the icon of the notifications.
The problem is that when the notification received with the text the icon gets cropped and it looks very bad.
after the ticker ends the icon looks fine.
I added a image with how it's look when the notification arriving and after the ticker is finished.
[image: the upper image is the icon when the notification arrived]

I can't use notificationCompat because my app needs to support api level 8.
how can I fix this problem without changing the size of the icon to 36X36 px?
this problem only happens in nexus 4 and htc one, in all of the samsung devices i checked (s2 4.1.2, s2 4.0.3, s3 4.1.2, s4 4.2.2, galaxy y) it works fine.

thanks in advanace

Edit:

I managed to make the notification not to be cropped.
BUT! when I add ticker Text (which is something I must add) the notification gets cropped again.
What could make that happen?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

notification icon must be 24x24 dp for optimal solution on most devices.

see

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification

or create the following notification sizes:

- 96x96px in drawable-xxxhdpi
- 72x72px size in drawable-xxhdpi
- 48x48px in drawable-xhdpi
- 36x36px in drawable-hdpi
- 24x24px in drawable-mdpi
- 18x18px in drawable-ldpi

also it better to centerized your icon in the middle of the icon image with transparent space around it.

**Google has updated their icon design page, here is another link that shows the optimum icon sizes for you app resources.**

http://www.creativepulse.gr/en/blog/2014/icon-sizes-for-android-apps

Comment: but then when I open the notification drawer the icon is small.
I'm looking for a solution that when the notification arrive and the ticker start I will see right sized Icon and when I open the notification drawer I will see a large Icon (and all that without using notificationCompat).

Comment: @ShalomMelamed use .setSmallIcon and .setLargeIcon with two different drawables

Comment: alse use 72x72px size in drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: This is the accepted answer? That just makes the icon fit in one place and shrink in the other, as @ShalomMelamed pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Eclipse, you can create notification icon set via standard wizard.

1. Go to File->New->Other
2. Select Android->Android icon set
3. Select "Notification Icons" option, enter resource name and press "Next"
4. Choose "Image" for Foreground and browse for your icon file
5. Press "Finish"

The wizard will create a drawable resource which you will use in setSmallIcon(). I created my notification icons in such way, and it looked fine with the ticker.

Comment: I tried using this tool, and it just generated silhouettes of my base image in different sizes. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: According to the Color guidelines in http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification, "Notification icons must be entirely white."